# Ensute linking / pivot table insert is unique in Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've got a linking table that needs to each link to be unique. So team_id 1 can only be in competition_id 1 once.

Does Laravel have any nice way to enforce this?

```
$competitionTeam = new CompetitionTeam();
$competitionTeam->competition_id = $competition_id;
$competitionTeam->team_id = $team_id;
$competitionTeam->save();
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a unique index on those two columns in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can checkout the Eloquent Relationships in documentation.

[Eloquent Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)

Basically what you need to do is while creating Eloquent model you have to define what type of relation you have between tables. I think One-to-Many relation will do your business.

Comment: I'd done this, but I named my columns a little wrong so it didn't know how to do it's magic behind the scenes.

Comment: The hardest part of database design is the naming part. After you name your tables appropriately you should think the connections between tables. If a single table only connects to a different single table it is one-to-one and vice versa.